# Load Facebook into an iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I can't load facebook into an iframe, in a web page like the following one:

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- some stuffs here -->
</head>
<body>
<!-- some stuffs here -->
<iframe src="http://www.google.com" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tested it with other websites and it seems to load without problems for instance for `wired.com`, but not for `facebook.com`...

Can anyone explain me why?

I'm using Google Chrome and Safari, if needed.

It seems to be as if Google blocks iframe loading of its page.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you use Firebug or Google Chrome's developer console, you can see the following error

```
Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.
```

**[X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header)**

> **DENY** 
>   The page cannot be displayed in a frame, regardless of the site attempting to do so.
>
> **SAMEORIGIN** 
>   The page can only be displayed in a frame on the same origin as the page itself.

Here is another related stackoverflow question
[Overcoming “Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options)

Answer (score 7):

Google and Facebook are using a X-Frame-Options in the HTTP response header to avoid the content being loaded in a iFrame.

> The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate
>   whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a
>    or  . Sites can use this to avoid clickjacking
>   attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded into other
>   sites.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header

I don't think it is possible for you to override this setting.

Comment: Isn't it possible to use iframes anyway, if I build a Google Chrome extension (by requesting some permission, or similar, in the manifest file)...

Comment: I would suggest looking at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6767901/394381 which suggest a hack on how to overcome this. However I haven't looked at how google chrome extension are able to load an iFrame.