# How to open facebook page inside iframe

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-iframe

I want to open Facebook page inside iframe but does not render page when I try to just include IFrame with `src` pointing to Facebook.com. Right now I am opening it inside a window but want to open it inside a frame.

Is there any way to open Facebook page in IFrame?

Comment: Have you read the Facebook docs on how to use FB as your login system? It gives good instructions on how to load the JavaScript SDK to log users into your site with Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load Facebook into an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680215/load-facebook-into-an-iframe)

Answer (score 4):

Facebook, as most serious sites explicitly disallow this in order to prevent [clickjacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking).

One of the ways Facebook do this is by sending the '[X-frame-options:deny](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header)' header, which instructs your browser to not display the page inside an iframe.

Comment: What do you mean by "most serious sites"?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a facebook page within your own website?

If so;

```
  <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com"></iframe>
```

If not could you provide more information.

Update
See below comment. It seems Facebook blocks it's pages from being includes in iframes.

Comment: That won't work as Facebook doesn't allow itself to be loaded in iframes. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680215/load-facebook-into-an-iframe

Comment: i just want to load facebook login page to do only login not access to the  whole facebook site.Can i perform this only..

Comment: No @pallavi, I suggest redirecting them to the site or opening in a popup like you have already done.