# open link from one page into iframe on toher page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want to do something where i have a link on a page called home.php that links to facebook , when you click on this link i want it to take you to a page called frame.php with a header at the top and the facebook link in an iframe. like this: http://themeforest.net/item/ime-portfolio-web-app/full_screen_preview/2918523 can anyone advise what the best way to do this is. If you look in the source of that link you'll see they have a header followed by an iframe with the previous link propagated into it.

Hope this all makes sense, if not heres some basic coding of what I'm trying to acheive:

```
<a href="Send-to-iframe:http://facebook.com">link</a>
```

---Next Page

```
<header>My website name/logo</header>

<iframe src="propagated iframe link from previous page">
```

Comment: ok what would you recommend if not that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new page which contains the header and an iframe below.  This page needs to take a URL in via the query-string and then output the url as the src of the iframe.

An example PHP page (iframe.php) (Just the bare minimum stuff):

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div id="header">Your header</div>
<iframe src="<?$_GET['url']?>"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Then you call this page like so:

```
<a href="/iframe.php?url=whatever.html">Open page</a>
```

This should give you an idea how it's done, but note that you might need to check the incoming URL and only allow certain domains etc. in case you do not want users to be able to open what ever URL they want through your iframe.php page.

Comment: Facebook can't be loaded in an iframe.

Comment: My answer was meant to be a general solution to the question.  Of course some sites break out of iframes and then this will not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible since your cannot load Facebook in an iframe, [it's forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680215/load-facebook-into-an-iframe).
Otherwise, your *frame.php* page could have simply contained a `<header>` and the `<iframe>` below.